# BouncyCastle BlowFish Crypto issue

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle, blowfish

here is my BlowFishCrypto Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Math;
namespace Common.Encryption
{
    public class BlowfishCryptographer
    {
        private bool forEncryption;
        private IBufferedCipher cipher;

        public BlowfishCryptographer(bool forEncryption)
        {
            this.forEncryption = forEncryption;
            cipher = new BufferedBlockCipher(new CfbBlockCipher(new BlowfishEngine(), 64));
            cipher.Init(forEncryption, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("DR654dt34trg4UI6")), new byte[8]));
        }
        public void ReInit(byte[] IV,BigInteger pubkey)
        {
            cipher.Init(forEncryption, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(pubkey.ToByteArrayUnsigned()),IV));
        }
        public byte[] DoFinal()
        {
            return cipher.DoFinal();
        }
        public byte[] DoFinal(byte[] buffer)
        {
           return cipher.DoFinal(buffer);
        }
        public byte[] DoFinal(byte[] buffer, int startIndex, int len)
        {
            return cipher.DoFinal(buffer, startIndex, len);
        }
        public byte[] ProcessBytes(byte[] buffer)
        {
            return cipher.ProcessBytes(buffer);
        }
        public byte[] ProcessBytes(byte[] buffer, int startIndex, int len)
        {
            return cipher.ProcessBytes(buffer, startIndex, len);
        }
        public void   Reset()
        {
            cipher.Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

in my other class i tried to test it so i made it like this

```
 BlowfishCryptographer incomingCipher=new BlowfishCryptographer(true);
 BlowfishCryptographer outgoingCipher=new BlowfishCryptographer(false);

byte[] buffer = new byte[] { 0x83, 0x00, 0xEE, 0x03, 0x26, 0x6D, 0x14, 0x00, 0xF1, 0x65, 0x27, 0x00, 0x19, 0x02, 0xD8, 0x0F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xDB, 0xD7, 0x0F, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2B, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0xE4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xDD, 0x0A, 0x18, 0x19, 0x00, 0x00, 0x79, 0x91, 0x87, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xA8, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x34, 0x00, 0x6A, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x0A, 0x7E, 0x42, 0x6C, 0x75, 0x65, 0x57, 0x61, 0x76, 0x65, 0x7E, 0x00, 0x09, 0x42, 0x6C, 0x61, 0x63, 0x6B, 0x44, 0x75, 0x73, 0x74 };

Console.WriteLine("\n\nBuffer\n" + outPutHex.ToHex(buffer));
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nBuffer enc\n" + outPutHex.ToHex(outgoingCipher.DoFinal(buffer)));
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nBuffer dec\n" + outPutHex.ToHex(incomingCipher.DoFinal(buffer)));
```

outputhex func will out put the result as hex

```
public static String ToHex(byte[] buf)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var b in buf) builder.Append(b.ToString("X2")+ " ");
            return builder.ToString();
        }
```

so the result is:

```
Buffer
83 00 EE 03 26 6D 14 00 F1 65 27 00 19 02 D8 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 DB D7 0F 08 00
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2B 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00 41 0
0 64 00 E4 00 00 00 DD 0A 18 19 00 00 79 91 87 00 00 01 00 A8 02 00 00 64 00 00
00 34 00 6A 18 00 00 00 00 00 00 C2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 00 03 0A 7E 42 6C 75 65 57 61 76 65 7E 00 09 42 6C 61 63 6B 44 75 73 74


Buffer enc
EB 28 65 06 EF B5 B9 3E 01 2F D0 B4 C2 25 4C 9C E2 05 D8 B5 93 AC F9 0F 92 87 8B
 5D 1E 45 F6 59 F8 FE 57 A8 0D CF 6C 6B E8 8D F9 88 A6 1D 6D 05 CC B8 6A 9F B0 8
D 13 70 AB F6 3F F8 DD EA ED 16 C3 DB A6 77 B2 46 29 0B DA F4 E2 FF A4 BA 6F C0
06 28 71 57 08 C8 EC 0F 65 54 13 46 C1 23 08 A5 28 C9 9F 9F 1D AD F9 66 09 A7 3B
 E3 22 64 A3 A0 8C 90 BC 1A 99 F1 4F F6 73 49 32 10 78 7D CF FF 68 01 75


Buffer dec
EB 28 65 06 EF B5 B9 3E B7 BE A2 2A 3D 92 5F D5 CF E3 D5 09 C0 5B 9D AD 01 D6 E4
 6D 73 3A 66 59 A9 83 10 11 80 FE 31 48 68 28 A0 01 C9 D8 AD 3E 38 B7 42 4B E5 E
5 56 44 99 91 E8 72 F0 C9 2B AF 83 8C 35 33 6E 08 CA 1E F0 3F 59 E8 64 8D A6 1C
CE 6E FF DC D6 3A FC D0 80 5B 36 81 06 FA 4E 0F 0B FA 54 CA C0 AD 32 52 68 28 8B
 05 CA D2 D3 7C 90 48 93 71 99 CE 28 0B 38 F2 8E 93 74 2F B1 67 9E 68 3F
```

it's not working but why?

Comment: Where is your `outPutHex.ToHex()` function? The _first_ output doesn't look anything like the buffer set in your testing class: `0x83 0x00 0xEE 0x03` becomes `73 00 EC 03`. With the first output being wrong 50% in the first four bytes, I wouldn't even bother looking at the `enc` and `dec` output. (Which are identical for the first eight bytes? Oops.) I suggest showing _all_ your code. You might be surprised how often bugs are in the input or output routines...

Comment: @sarnold - i updated the question! u can check it
edit: the decryption not working at all!!

Comment: It _looks_ like it should work, but the fact that the first `Buffer` in your output doesn't match what is in your code is a large cause for concern. Try testing your `ToHex()` on a larger variety of inputs to see if you can find out where it goes wrong.

Comment: @sarnold oh dman soz i copied a wrong output i updated the question again with the right buffers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem:

```
Console.WriteLine("\n\nBuffer\n" + outPutHex.ToHex(buffer));
Console.WriteLine("\n\nBuffer enc\n" +
    outPutHex.ToHex(outgoingCipher.DoFinal(buffer)));
Console.WriteLine("\n\nBuffer dec\n" +
    outPutHex.ToHex(incomingCipher.DoFinal(buffer)));
```

You're creating two cipher contexts `incomingCipher` and `outgoingCipher`. You run them both on the *same input* `buffer`. This could be useful if you were checking against [test vectors](http://www.schneier.com/blowfish.html), but the two certainly won't be the same.

Try:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[] { 0x83, 0x00, /* etc */ }

byte[] enc = incomingCipher.DoFinal(buffer);
byte[] dec = outgoingCipher.DoFinal(enc);

Console.WriteLine("\n\nBuffer\n" + outPutHex.ToHex(buffer));
Console.WriteLine("\n\nBuffer enc\n" + outPutHex.ToHex(enc));
Console.WriteLine("\n\nBuffer dec\n" + outPutHex.ToHex(dec));
```

Comment: i see, but is the class will work like that or it's need some edits?

Comment: @Mixed, well, it depends; if the output is the same with both the original `Buffer` and `Buffer dec` lines, then your class is probably going to work fine, unchanged. If the outputs are _different_, then you need to investigate _why_ they are different.