# What is the best library I can use for BlowFish/DH?

Tags: c#, cryptography, blowfish, diffie-hellman

What is the best library I can use for BlowFish/DH, because I was using BouncyCastle but it looks like it does not do what I want, so I was wondering if there is another library I can use so it let me work with CFB/DH? Thanks

And here is my BouncyCastle class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Math;


namespace Common.Encryption
{
    public class BlowfishCryptographer
    {
        private bool forEncryption;
        private IBufferedCipher cipher;

        public BlowfishCryptographer(bool forEncryption)
        {
            this.forEncryption = forEncryption;
            cipher = new BufferedBlockCipher(new CfbBlockCipher(new BlowfishEngine(), 64));
            cipher.Init(forEncryption, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("DR654dt34trg4UI6")), new byte[8]));
        }
        public void ReInit(byte[] IV,BigInteger pubkey)
        {
            cipher.Init(forEncryption, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(pubkey.ToByteArrayUnsigned()),IV));
        }
        public byte[] DoFinal()
        {
            return cipher.DoFinal();
        }
        public byte[] DoFinal(byte[] buffer)
        {
           return cipher.DoFinal(buffer);
        }
        public byte[] DoFinal(byte[] buffer, int startIndex, int len)
        {
            return cipher.DoFinal(buffer, startIndex, len);
        }
        public byte[] ProcessBytes(byte[] buffer)
        {
            return cipher.ProcessBytes(buffer);
        }
        public byte[] ProcessBytes(byte[] buffer, int startIndex, int len)
        {
            return cipher.ProcessBytes(buffer, startIndex, len);
        }
        public void   Reset()
        {
            cipher.Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is CFB/DH? I've never heard of that mode.

Comment: Why the hell would you want to use Blowfish in 2011? To quote Bruce Schneier "At this point, though, I'm amazed it's still being used."

Comment: I don't know what `CFB/DH` mode is -- even searching for `CFB DH` returns **this question** as the top hit on a major search engine. You would probably do better to stick with a more common [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_of_operation).

Comment: @Sarnold I think CFB means [Cipher Feed Back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_.28CFB.29) and DH means [Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie-Hellman_key_exchange) as this question is tagged with it. (I tried searching each individually on wikipedia), what he wants with those I do not know.

Comment: @Yet, aha! That makes sense. Well, no, it doesn't make sense, but it probably explains what MixedCoder meant, anyway. When I [helped him debug this class earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481762/bouncycastle-blowfish-crypto-issue), I never saw any mention of Diffie-Hellman, so the possibility never crossed my mind here. That says something about making assumptions. :)

Answer (score 0):

The source code for an implementation is fairly easy to stumble across on the internet thingy.

Is this what you are after?

http://www.schneier.com/code/blowfish.cs